# Hello World Android App, Error: workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

I am a totally newbie who just got into Android development. I am going through the `"Building your first app`" tutorial on the official Android developer webpage. I followed all the instruction but it shows me this error code in Eclipse. The error message is real long and I guess there must be something wrong in my setting, SDK, or environment. Can anybody help me out in resolving this problem? For your information, my target SDK is `API19` and I am also compiling it with `API19`

```
[2014-10-22 17:13:51 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-10-22 17:13:51 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-10-22 17:13:51 - appcompat_v7] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin\jarlist.cache
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:110: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:107: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:121: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:126: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:138: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:143: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:129: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:132: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:146: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:150: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:154: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:158: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:164: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:168: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:172: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:174: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:93: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:97: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:101: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:62: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:22: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:24: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:28: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:30: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:32: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:38: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:40: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:42: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:60: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:46: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:50: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:52: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:54: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:56: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base_text.xml:58: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:26: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:31: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:36: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Dialog'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:338: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:29: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:345: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:37: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:352: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:45: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v11\themes_base.xml:359: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v14\themes_base.xml:53: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:actionModeShareDrawable'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:202: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:212: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Light'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:205: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:219: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:223: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:ThemeOverlay.Material.Dark.ActionBar'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:81: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:83: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:84: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:82: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:79: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:80: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:118: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:120: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:121: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:119: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:116: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:117: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:155: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:157: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:158: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:156: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:153: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:154: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:192: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorAccent'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:194: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlActivated'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:195: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:193: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlNormal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:190: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:53 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\themes_base.xml:191: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:33: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:37: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:41: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:65: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:69: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:45: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:49: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:53: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:57: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:61: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:178: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:182: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:113: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
[2014-10-22 17:13:57 - MyFirstApp] C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:115: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: have you tried refreshing and cleaning your whole project?

Comment: Yeah, I clear all my workspace and redownload the ADT bundle, still same error.

Comment: Try this Go to Project->Properties->Java build path. On the "Order and Export" tab, make sure all the libraries your project is referring to are checked.

Comment: Is the project appCompatV7 is open or shown in your workSpace?

Comment: whoa, I didn't export Android 4.4.2 to it. But after i fixed it, the errors are still there.

Comment: In the Java Build Path, the Libraries tab says that "appcompat_v7.jar-C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\appcompat_v7\bin(missing)"

Comment: Hey Cliff, see my answer, the problem is a conflict by having 2 references of android-support-v4.jar in a single project.

Answer (score 23):

> For your information, my target SDK is API19 and I am also compiling it with API19

Use API21 (or greater) for target and compile.

API 19 does no know the material stuff that is missing.

To do this with Eclipse, set your own project to target API21 (or greater): open *Project Properties* and in the *Android* pane, specify *Project Build Tagret* as API21 (or greater). When *Project Build Tagret* of your own project is below 21, errors in the question appear. Clean and re-build your own project when modified its *Project Build Tagret*.

Answer (score 13):

I found the source of the problem, when we create a new project, it contains the reference of the `appcompat_v7` library:

[image]

the `appcompat_v7` library already contains the support library "`android-support-v4.jar`"

[image]

the problem is that the new project created contains into the `/libs` folder, the library "`android-support-v4.jar`" too!, just delete this .jar from your new project ( that is already contained into the `appcompat_v7` library)

don´t forget to `clean and build your project`

**This problem happens using API 19 use API 21 or later**

Comment: Tried this and unfortunately it did not work for me. Simply comment in an effort to let others know this may not work.

Comment: Well, now you have to comment a lot of answers here =) . This problem happens using API 19 try using API 21 or later.

Comment: You are correct. Nothing seems to work.  This is on a machine where I've built projects before and those project still build.  I've tried targeting the latest API (and numerous others) still nothing.

Comment: Ok daylight , your problem must be related to other issue, please post a question and paste the link here as a comment! :)

Answer (score 6):

This is because of Eclipse and SDK relation upon the **"appcompact_v7"** library project.

When we create a new **Android Application Project**, eclipse try to add a library(appcompact_v7) project for it.If we create our project with **target 19 (API 19)**, eclipse will also generate the **appcompact_v7** library project with **API 19**. When we clean and build the application, we got error like as follow:

```
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:79: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'.
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:83: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:25: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'.
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:29: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'.
```

> Why? Because **when eclipse create appcompact_v7, it retrieve all reference for every SDK version from your SDK manager**. So, in **appcompact_v7**, there will be reference for SDK which is greater than API 19.

Ok, check this part in the log: `appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml:75`. That shown, it can't compile reference for `values-v21`(means target 21(API 21)). Therefore, it shown error like that.

So, what we need to do. We need to do is, **the compile target for appcompact_v7 project always must be the latest API of the related SDK**.

I also found this error because my latest is **API 23** and I compile it wit **API 22**. So, I got this error:

```
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base.xml:20: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
....\appcompat_v7\res\values-v23\styles_base_text.xml:19: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
```

So, I change the android target in `project.properties` of appcompact_v7 to latest as follow:

[image]

Also in `project.properties` of project as follow:

[image]

After that, I clean and compile the project. It has shown no error.

Answer (score 4):

You will see the error at values-v21, it is said that you have not install Android API21.
if you install the Android API21,the error will disappear automatically.

Answer (score 3):

1. Update the project.properties file of **appcompat v7**, which has:`target=android-19` to `target=android-21`
2. Also update `google play services` library

Comment: Mine is already at anroid-21 but I still get the error above. Documenting in an attempt to help others who are experiencing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

One anther thing you ca try is to open the project.properties file of the android-support-v7-appcompat and change the target target=android-21 (latest).
Afterwards just do a Project --> Clean... so that the changes take effect.

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps:

1. In Eclipse, right click on current project, click on Import... then choose General > Existing Projects into Workspace.
2. Use "Select root directory:" and browse for local folder containing "adt-bundle-windows" in pathname, which typically looks something like "C:\Development\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat". Select that appcompat folder.
3. Under Projects:, android-support-v7-appcompat should be checked. IMPORTANT: Make sure "Copy projects into workspace" is also checked.
4. Click finish.
5. android-support-v7-appcompat project will appear under Package Explorer. Go to File > New > Android Application Project, create a new project and you'll see that appcompat_v7 now is built each time a new project is created.
6. android-support-v7-appcompat project can be deleted now. After doing this, it'll stop working for the current project and errors will appear. Do this next...
7. Right click on current project, go to Properties.
8. Click on Android, then under Library click on Add... and select appcompat_v7 to associate with your current project. Remove android-support-v7-appcompat from the list. Now appcompat_v7 will appear as its own project in your workspace (and it'll probably fix the bin folder), and your current project should hopefully now work.

Comment: i'm so sorry but the problem still persist. I am getting a new error `[2014-10-22 18:37:11 - android-support-v7-appcompat] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file C:\Users\Cliff\workspace\android-support-v7-appcompat\bin\jarlist.cache
`

Comment: @Cliff hmm... look at http://www.androidpit.com/forum/616541/trying-to-start-hello-world-in-eclipse-getting-errors and try the suggestion there to see if it helps... it says to just refresh the appcompat_v7 folder or change the jarlist cache destination/ location

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I resolve this by following four steps:

> 1) right click on **appcompat_v7** library
>
> 2) go to properties
>
> 3) select android
>
> 4) set target upper than 19 api then apply and ok

Finally, this error remove.