# Eclipse new project errors

Tags: android, eclipse, path, project, android-appcompat

Everything starts out fine with setting up the workspace and project, but I can'at run as an application because there are errors I can't clear. I have tried building java paths and downloading sdk tools and libraries.

and then these errors occur... I did try to connect to appcompat v7 jar, but it did not work. I am a beginner to Eclipse it would be nice if anyone can give some detailed answers and solutions please. 
The errors are specifically:

```
  error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given 
  name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'.  styles_base.xml /appcompat_v7/res/values-v21

  The container 'Android Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\Documents\Android Experiments\appcompat_v7\bin\appcompat_v7.jar'
```

The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved

Answer (score 0):

You may want to search for similar posts here at oDesk, ie: [Hello World Android App, Error: workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml No resource found that matches the given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518144/hello-world-android-app-error-workspace-appcompat-v7-res-values-v21-styles-bas)

AFAIK the first issue happens when you install Android-L SDK, it somehow conflicts with Eclipse's new project wizard (the wizard adds those resource files with errors, you can just remove them in res folder)

About the second issue - probably you need to fix path to appcompat_v7.jar file, see the post where it is in project settings. It may fix the first issue as well, I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

It's time to switch to android studio even though it's beta the build is .8 which should suffice as significant evidence that it's nearing release.  The gradle builds with appcompat are seamless automatic it's so much easier than eclipse to use external libraries.

This is all it takes in the build.gradle with android studio.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21+'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:21+"
```

}