# Eclipse Android project - appcompat_v7\res\values-v21 - No resource found that matches the given name

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, material-design, android-appcompat

I tried to create a new Android project, but at the beginning (after the project configuration) I've got these errors:

[image]

Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: Do you have Androidmanifest.xml file?

Comment: Where can I find it? I'm beginner and this is my first school project.

Comment: I suppose, you're using Eclipse for making done tutorials. Better way is to from scratch doing everything in Android Studio. You won't then get tis errors ;-)

Comment: I tried to download Android studio, but I have an old computer and when download completes Google chrome reports "System is busy".

Answer (score 0):

It means that some Material Design stuff is incompatible with your minSDK or targetSDK version.

In Eclipse, set your own project to target API 21 (or greater):

- open Project Properties and in the Android panel, s
- specify Project Build Target as API21 (or greater).

When Project Build Target of your own project is below 21, errors in the question appear. Clean and re-build your own project when modified its Project Build Target.

Also check this answer from [Hello World Android App, Error: workspace\appcompat_v7\res\values-v21\styles_base.xml No resource found that matches the given name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518144/hello-world-android-app-error-workspace-appcompat-v7-res-values-v21-styles-bas)

> I found the source of the problem, when we create a new project, it
>   contains the reference of the `appcompat_v7` library:
>
> [image]
>
> the `appcompat_v7` library already contains the support library
>   "`android-support-v4.jar`"
>
> [image]
>
> the problem is that the new project created contains into the `/libs`
>   folder, the library "`android-support-v4.jar`" too!, just delete this
>   .jar from your new project ( that is already contained into the
>   `appcompat_v7` library)
>
> don´t forget to `clean and build your project`
>
> **This problem happens using API 19 use API 21 or later**

Hope it help